# Emtpy a file while using cat on it

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I wrote a bash script that uses `cat` to write the contents of one file into another. However I want the file that is being written into to be emptied, essentially everytime it has been written into. My current code only empties the file upon start.

The code:

```
#!/bin/ash
while true
do
cat /dev/rs232 > /tmp/regfile
> /dev/rs232
sleep 1
> /tmp/regfile
done
```

EDIT:
To make the purpose maybe a bit clearer, I'm trying to read `/tmp/regfile` with another program (to publish the output to a MQTT broker), which doesn't have the capability to read `/dev/rs232` directly (so my program is supposed to be the workaround for that). `/dev/rs232` receives a new string constantly. The `sleep 1` is since it can only publish every second.

Comment: That is purpose of using a `fifo`

Comment: Problem is not really clear... if you do `cat something > file` the `>` will overwrite the file every time... if you want to append, you should do `>>`

Comment: `emptied, essentially everytime it has been written into` So the file will be always empty? Is this XY question? Do you want to ex. keep the last line in the file instead?

Comment: You could write to `/dev/null` instead; the purpose of writing to `/tmp/regfile` in the first place isn't clear. Do you ever try to *read* the contents of `/tmp/regfile`?

Comment: Ah, I"m assuming the goal here is to empty out `/dev/rs232`. If that's the case, writing to `/dev/null` is absolutely what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully make the goal a bit more clear

Comment: What about creating a symnlink of `/dev/rs232`  to somewhere, instead of an endless loop with cat?

Comment: `The sleep 1 is since it can only publish every second.` So you want to wait 1 second, read all the data _up until this point in time buffered in /dev/rs232_ and save them in regfile, each second?

Comment: @KamilCuk if I understood you correctly, yes. Basically: receive input to `/dev/rs232` -> read it out and write it into `/tmp/regfile` -> emtpy `/dev/rs232` so the next input doesn't append itself to the old one -> `sleep 1` so the mqtt publisher has time to publish -> clear `/tmp/regfile` so that it doesn't append anything or publish the same content twice

Comment: `sleep 1 so the mqtt publisher has time to publish` Do not use sleep as synchronization. Employ real synchronization mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to constantly read from rs232, cause most probably device file does not have any buffer. So, then you have to buffer the input yourself. Then, each 1 second, you can flush the buffer into the file.

```
# Using cat to have hopefully 4K buffer in pipe
# Would be better to use `stdbuf -o4K` explicitly.
cat /dev/rs232 |
while true; do
     # reading data for one second
     data=$(timeout 1 cat)  # TODO: handle errors, so it does not loop endlessly
     # Write data to regfile.
     # This should be fast enough or the buffer from the device
     # should be big enough so that `cat /dev/rs232` will not notice
     # that we stopped reading from stdin.
     # Ideally, this would be asynchronously in another process or thread.
     printf "%s" "$data" > /tmp/regfile
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to employ this and see how it goes. About the synchronization mechanisms I will have to see, since the environment this is running doesn't have a internet connection and not much storage for libraries (<3MB)

Answer (score 1):

one way to empty a file,
`>filename`

if you want to be efficient then there is also,
`truncate -s 0 filename`